# Java doesn't find solution package in resource folder Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, resources

This sample is supposed to locate the copied over .zip file from the build output directory but for some reason it doesn't find that file. I created a resource directory in the root directory and marked it as "Resource Root" and still didn't work. Any help is appreciated. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
if (install && package == null) {
    File file = new File("file.zip");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    inputStream.read(bytes);
    inputStream.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found.");
        return;
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error Reading The File.");
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of the project structure:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS2p3.png)

Comment: "Copy"? That involves either a file object copy op or some kind of writing. Neither appears in your code. Also, as far as your read op goes, you should know that is not guaranteed to read the whole file. You need ```java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes```. But there are better ways of copying files if that's your objective

Comment: @g00se sorry my bad! I meant locate the copied over file.

Comment: Could be a [current directory](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/91-find-the-current-directory-in-java)
problem

Comment: It is pointing at the root directory

Comment: Please give the actual value of 'customSolutionFilename'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean you've created the file in the `/main/resources` folder of your project?

If that's so, then you can copy it as such:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    var path = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/myfile.txt");
    Files.copy(path, Path.of("file.txt"));
}
```